# Conflict between blur on textarea and submit on input button

Tags: jquery

I have a text area and a button. I have code that extends the text area on focus and shrinks on blur event. When the user presses the button, it submits the content to server. The issue is that when user types text and then clicks the button, it results in blur event on text area before the click on button. The box shrinks but the button click action gets masked. I have gone through various threads on similar topic and have already tried various options but neither worked...

1. tried to add this in blur handler... but didn't help...

   ```
   if ($(':focus').is('#submitbtn')) { return false; }
   ```
2. tried adding this to blur handler... but it didn't work in IE even though it worked in Chrome...

   ```
   if (event.relatedTarget != null && event.relatedTarget.nodeName == "INPUT") {

     // Now call click on the related Target which was the submit button

     event.relatedTarget.click();

   }
   ```
3. tried following approach but didn't help...

   ```
   $("#myTextArea").blur(function(evt) {

       if (evt.target is not the button){ //pseudo code

         //do something 

         return true; // I handled it

       }

       return false; // I didn't handle it

   })
   ```

Any other solutions?

Comment: can u make fiddle so we have better idea..!

Comment: Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/mi10/csYkk/5/

Note that I found 2 hacks and have added them to the code. One works for IE and another works for Chrome and Firefox... I am sure though that there is a better solution.... 

Note that in this demo the problem doesn't show up because of the hacks. If you remove those hacks, you will the issue...

Answer (score 1):

Well its tricky .. i donot know why but its capture the button focus but not click .. here is code  where if submit button have focus submit the form..  (hope its help.. as i know its not complete fix)

```
$("#btn_0").focus(function() {  
/*its capture the focus but not the click*/
  $("#f1").submit();
});
```

[**Working dmeo**](http://jsfiddle.net/csYkk/10/)

Comment: This certainly helps just like other 2 hacks I did. Many thanks for helping here. But there are few issues with this like any other hacks. e.g. many times, it doesn't clear the text area after submit. Also if I just do tabbing through my controls, it will submit as soon as the button gets the focus. :-( Yes, it is certainly very tricky... My 2 hacks also has the issue of tabbing through button, submits the comment... Any other thoughts? Anyone else?

Comment: I think clearing data etc u have to take care its not normal submit its kind of from js so u have to do something like this in btn.focus -  $("#t0").html(""); problem is we donot know btn focus come bcaz of click or normal focus.. !!!